# Read a dynamic MySQL with PHP

Tags: mysql

I have a dynamic MySQL-Table with 20 columns and 1 Row where id = 1. The new data will be added to the table as the sencond row where id = 2, And so an. I need to read the newest data row (always the last id). How should I write the query to read the last row?

How should I change this:

`$sql = "SELECT id, AbW_L, PuVor_L ,Durchfluss ,... FROM table order by id desc ";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by `id` descending, and limit the results to one row:

```
SELECT * from table order by id desc limit 1;
```

Comment: I want to read each field of this 20 columns. What is the correct code in php?

Comment: @point_system Use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). But that's outside the scope of this question. I suggest you read a tutorial on PHP and databases.

Comment: Actually I need a code that gives me the value of each field of this 20 Columns in the last updated id. I have a Code that doesn't suit my DB. How should I change it?
http://www.codeshare.io/wNXfV

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/order_by.php
It will give you more detailed information on what to do, however based on that one line of code, just change it to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
```

Should work no problem. If you want to add limits, you can do:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10";
```

I selected 10 as the limit in the example, you can pick whatever number you would like to use.

Comment: And how can I select the value of fields in each columb with php ?

Comment: so a while/foreach loop.